# In PostgreSQL How To find UTC date time from other time zone date time

Tags: postgresql

I have IST date time, I need to find UTC time & date from IST date in PostgreSQL.

At '2023-01-06T16:35:21.628+11:00' this time what was the UTC time I need to find. this time is as per IST time zone.
I am new in PostgreSQL.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Please add code samples.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

UTC time & date is given by :

```
SELECT '2023-01-06T16:35:21.628+11:00' :: timestamp with time zone AT time zone 'utc'
```

UTC date is given by :

```
SELECT ('2023-01-06T16:35:21.628+11:00' :: timestamp with time zone AT time zone 'utc') :: date
```

UTC time is givven by :

```
SELECT ('2023-01-06T16:35:21.628+11:00' :: timestamp with time zone AT time zone 'utc') :: time
```

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PjW7ztNp)